# What happened with the answer ratio?

Tags: discussion

This morning the answer questions percentage was at 88%.
Not it's 82%. [image: 82-wth].

I doubt that in one day were added about 450+ unanswered questions that would represent 6% of the total number of questions (about 8k).

Comment: I've been asking a *lot* of questions in meta lately :P

Comment: Bug, bug, bug :-(

http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233979/how-are-beta-site-statistics-calculated

Comment: @Tim. So which one is the correct value: 82 or 88? By my calculations it should be around 90%.

Comment: We will see soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oddly I think it is correct, unless my basic maths failed again. I wonder if something happened to a lot of our questions.

We currently have:

```
8010: total questions
1433: question without an up voted answer
```

I blame Ben for actually advertising the website ;)

Comment: Hmmm. I thought "unanswered questions" were calculated differently. for me "unanswered questions" means "questions without an answer". But I guess you are right....Oh...and I also blame Ben for everything also. :)

Comment: @Marius think that a big part of the massive drop was because we have gone from around 20 questions per day to over 40....again this is all Ben's fault ;)